# What size chuck key do I need for my Black & Decker DNJ62 drill?

Tags: drill, chuck

I have been given an ancient Black and Decker DNJ62 power drill from my father (who knows even less about DIY than I - which is saying something).  Unfortunately he has lost the chuck key for it, which is something of a draw back.

Am I correct in thinking from the label attached below that I need a 13 mmm chuck key like this [one from Screwfix](https://www.screwfix.com/p/chuck-key-13mm/9714v) for this drill?

I fear I'm asking a stupid question here, but it did occur to me that the  13 mm below might refer to something else (maximum size of drill bit?) and it would be frustrating to get home with the wrong size chuck...

[image]

Comment: Look on the Chuck itself. There are many different keys based on the brand of the Chuck. Get the brand and model of the Chuck and it will be easy to find the right size. For example I have at least 3 different brands of 1/2" drill motors none use the same Chuck key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**13mm / 1/2"** refers to the size of the chuck which is also the maximum size bit, though there are some larger bits specifically designed to fit in a 1/2" drill, with a 1/2" shank and a larger tip.

[There are plenty of "universal" chuck keys](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001Z0WG38) available, which may be the best way to go. But you *should* be OK with [a 1/2" chuck key](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00002NBJI).

Comment: Get the universal. That drill is old enough to not conform to 'normal' conventions.